# Software installation offline

Tags: playonlinux

I have Desktop with ubuntu Linux installed. I don't have Internet Connection at home. I download Linux base application on USB Drive. How I can install those application in Ubuntu.
Help or guide me to install softwarae

Comment: What format are the applications? are they **.deb** pacakges?

Comment: yes they are .deb format

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install deb packages without a Internet connection.

you can use `dpkg -i <package name>`

example:

Download the package that you want.

copy the package to your `/home/<user>` folder.

Run this command. I am only using `PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb` as an example your package name may be different.

```
sudo dpkg -i  PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb
```

You must know `PlayOnLinux` and other packages have dependencies and you wont be able to install offline unless you have all the dependencies for the package downloaded or installed.

These are the dependencies for `PlayonLinux` are.

```
unzip, wget, xterm | x-terminal-emulator, python, python-wxgtk2.8 | python-wxgtk3.0, imagemagick, cabextract, icoutils, p7zip-full, curl
```

How to find a package Depends run this command. `package.deb` being your package name

```
dpkg -I package.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install **.deb** packages onto your system either by using the graphical manager [GDebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/) or through the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagename>
```

That should help you **:)**